# Preventing circular event triggers in jQuery/Coffeescript/Rails3.1.1

Tags: jquery

Here is a snippet of my jQuery code written in Coffeescript for a Rails 3.1.1 application:

```
$("#type_well_volume").change(->
    unless $(this).val() == ""
      $("#type_well_abandonment_rate").val("").attr "disabled", true
      $("#type_well_case_life").val("").attr "disabled", true
    else
      $("#type_well_abandonment_rate").attr "disabled", false
      $("#type_well_case_life").attr "disabled", false
  ).trigger "change"

  $("#type_well_case_life").change(->
    unless $(this).val() == ""
      $("#type_well_abandonment_rate").val("").attr "disabled", true
      $("#type_well_volume").val("").attr "disabled", true
    else
      $("#type_well_abandonment_rate").attr "disabled", false
      $("#type_well_volume").attr "disabled", false
  ).trigger "change"

  $("#type_well_abandonment_rate").change(->
    unless $(this).val() == ""
      $("#type_well_volume").val("").attr "disabled", true
      $("#type_well_case_life").val("").attr "disabled", true
    else
      $("#type_well_volume").attr "disabled", false
      $("#type_well_case_life").attr "disabled", false
  ).trigger "change"
```

As you can see, my intent is to allow only one of these three fields to be populated by the user, and as soon as the user enters a value for any one of these, grey-out (i.e., make read-only) the other two fields.  Additionally, when the DOM loads, I want the right event handler to trigger such that the field that has a value is open for edits and other two are greyed out.

The code shown above does not work reliably.  Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: The major thing is that attr changes the `attribute` not the `property`. As long as there exists an `attribute` "disabled" (doesn't matter if `disabled="false"` or `disabled="true"`), the disabled `property` will be true.

Comment: Appreciate the response.  The attribute enable/disable stuff works fine.  It is the circular dependency that is causing the problems.

Comment: I tested it on this very textfield so It's strange that it is actually working for you :-). I will add my answer

Comment: So this is precisely the behavior that I am getting with my original code.  That is: upon the initial page load if one of the fields has value, the other two fields are disabled -- this is good since this is the behavior that I want.  But, as soon as I edit the field that has a value and tab out, instead of the two disabled fields, only one is "re-enabled", is there a way to make sure that the event propagates to both the disabled fields and re-enables them?  Also, when I type in a value in the one of the re-enabled fields, the other two fields should be disabled.

Comment: I don't get it, it's working perfectly for me.
1. When I remove the prefilled field ("hi" becomes empty), and tab, all fields become available as should
2. When I type to some other opened field, and the change event is fired, the other fields become disabled, as should. Are you misunderstanding when the change event fires? I.E. you said "as soon as the user enters a value for any one of these". If you want that then the change event is the wrong event for you.

Comment: You are right.  Your example works fine in jsFiddle.  However my Coffeescript translation is misbehaving in my actual application code :(  Any tips on how to debug this?

Comment: Are you under some kind of punishment and all your code needs to be in coffeescript? :-) See what kind of regular js you get out of coffeescript and compare it to the js in my jsfiddle link

Comment: Thanks for staying with me.  I followed your suggestion and moved this piece of code to javascript/jQuery and inlined it in my form and it works perfectly!  It is a Rails 3.1.1/Coffeescript/Sprokets issue probably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this jsfiddle, is this equivalent functionality that you wanted?

http://jsfiddle.net/UkwFx/

Here is jsfiddle when one field is pre filled:

http://jsfiddle.net/UkwFx/1/